# Добавление гиперссылки к письму

Tags: java, html, email, link

После регистрации нужно отправить пользователю письмо с подтверждением.
В письме должна быть ссылка. Как сделать её кликабельной или это происходит автоматически? Нужны ли какие-либо теги/настройки для отправки письма?
Для отправки используется JavaMail API

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно отправить email в формате HTML. Для этого используйте вызов вроде этого:

```
message.setText(text, "utf-8", "html");
```

или этого:

```
message.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Ссылки лучше делать без лишних декораций и даже названий:

```
<p>Подтвердить регистрацию:<br><br>
<a href="http://www.example.com/register?code=XXX">http://www.example.com/register?code=XXX</a>
```

Клиенты разные, могут быть по-разному настроены и т.п. А регистрация — критический шаг, не до красот.

Если отправляете письмо в текстовом формате, то убедитесь, что ссылка полная и отбита от остального текста пробельными символами. Если ссылка длинная, но разместите её на отдельной строке. Избегайте ссылок длиннее примерно 70 символов.

Большинство почтовых клиентов преобразует ссылки вида `http://www.example.com/register?code=XXX` в кликаемые, но длинные ссылки могут испортиться переносами строк (ограничение формата).